# Why does adding a space in tag register the node as Comment_Node

Tags: dom, reactjs, jestjs, jsdom

I have the following piece of test code that is used with jest I load the React component in the "Dom".

```
const actionDropDownErrorNode =(data,myStyles={})=>{
    let actionDropDownErr = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
        <div><ActionDropDownError data={data || <div></div>} styles={myStyles}/></div>
    );

    return ReactDOM.findDOMNode(actionDropDownErr).firstChild;
};
```

now when I check the contents of the element

```
<span className={styles.solution || "solution"}>{data.solution}</span>
```

it returns a Text_Node which is what I want but if I alter the element to:

```
<span className={styles.solution || "solution"}>{data.solution} </span>
```

it returns a Comment_Node why is that ?

For reference purpose this is how I get the data.solution out of the element tag:

```
const elementContent = node =>{
if (node.nodeType === 1 && node.firstChild  !== null) {
    if (node.firstChild.nodeType ===3){
        elements.push(node.firstChild.textContent);
    }

}
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A space in JSX result to an empty string `" "`:

So this `<span className={styles.solution || "solution"}>{data.solution}</span>` will result to :

```
React.createElement(
  "span",
  { className: styles.solution || "solution" },
  data.solution
);
```

and this `<span className={styles.solution || "solution"}>{data.solution} </span>` will result to :

```
React.createElement(
  "span",
  { className: styles.solution || "solution" },
  data.solution,
  " "
);
```

Comment: yea but why does it register it as a comment_Node mdn says comments are represented as <!-- and -->

Comment: comment can be wrapped this way in JSX also, `{/* A JSX comment */}`